# File API and name encoding

Tags: firefox, web-applications, fileapi, firefox-os

I've just started to play with Firefox OS doing first app.

In app I'm using File API in order to get list of files in storage, but there is a problem here, I'm getting cyrillic paths in `name` property like this:

`Moonbeam/Moonbeam/Albums/(2008) ÐÑÐ¸ÐºÐ¾ÑÐ½Ð¾Ð²ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ [UL 077715]/07 ÐÐ´Ð¸Ð½ ÐÐµÐ½Ñ.mp3`

while correct should be

`Moonbeam/Moonbeam/Albums/(2008) Прикосновение [UL 077715]/07 Один День.mp3`

Not sure wether this is a bug inside Firefox OS Simulator or somewhere else. All files names in utf-8 encoding, I expected to get corresponding string.

Ubuntu 14.10 x64, Firefox 31.0, Firefox OS 1.4 Simulator

```
navigator.getDeviceStorage('music').enumerate().onsuccess = function () {
  var file = this.result;
  console.log(file.name);
  this.continue();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 File API's default encoding is UTF-8.

```
FileReader.readAsText(Blob|File, opt_encoding)
```

- The result property will contain the file/blob's data as a text string. By default the string is decoded as 'UTF-8'. Use the optional encoding parameter can specify a different format.

In my Firefox OS simulator, File API sample app is working to display Korean filnename characters based on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ In detail, please refer to [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744064/html5-file-api-reading-in-an-xml-text-file-and-displaying-it-on-the-page).

Comment: I'm not talking about file content, because it is binary music file.
I'm talkign about path I get in result of such code:
<code<pre>navigator.getDeviceStorage('music').enumerate().onsuccess = function () {
   var file = this.result;
   console.log(file.name);
   this.continue();
}
</pre></code>